# Alterar propriedade display de um <div> ao clicar em um <input>

Tags: javascript

Estou trabalhando em um formulário de contato no qual quando a pessoa clica no `<input>` aparece uma `<div>` ao lado, mencionando algumas coisas que a pessoa deve fazer. Ex: Insira aqui seu e-mail.

> Como fazer para que seja agregado a propriedade `display:block` nas `<div>`'s:

```
<div class="tooltip.right">
```

> Ao clicar nas `<input>`s:

```
<input class="form-control">
```

Obs: Quando a pessoa clicar fora do `<input>` altera para `display:none`. Javascript puro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sua pergunta ficou muito vaga, não tenho certeza se o input aponta pra um div especifico, se terão vários inputs e vários divs.

Todavia a resposta seria algo como:

Você pode usar a propriedade `.style` ou .className`:

1. style:

   ```js
       window.onload = function() {
            var div = document.querySelector("div[class='tooltip.right']");
            var input = document.querySelector(".form-control");

            input.onclick = function() {
                 div.style.display = "block";
            };

            input.onblur = function() {
                 div.style.display = "none";
            };
       };
   ```

   ```css
       div[class="tooltip.right"] {
             display: none;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <input class="form-control">
       <div class="tooltip.right">Olá mundo</div>
   ```
2. className:

   ```js
       window.onload = function() {
            var hideClass = /(^|\s)hide(\s|$)/;

            var div = document.querySelector("div[class*='tooltip.right']");
            var input = document.querySelector(".form-control");

            input.onclick = function() {
                 div.className = div.className.replace(hideClass, " ");
            };

            input.onblur = function() {
                 div.className += " hide";
            };
       };
   ```

   ```css
       .hide {
             display: none;
       }
   ```

   ```html
       <input class="form-control">
       <div class="tooltip.right hide">Olá mundo</div>
   ```

### Nota:

Recomendo que não use classes com ponto `class="tooltip.right"`, o ponto é um delimitador pra identificar as classes nos seletores CSS, seria melhor algo como:

```
<div class="tooltip.right hide">Olá mundo</div>
```

Ou se você estiver usado o ponto como separador e tooltip e right forem duas classes diferentes, então o correto pra separar no HTML é o espaço, assim:

```
<div class="tooltip right hide">Olá mundo</div>
```

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: Acho que não é bem o que procuro. É algo muito simples. Muito código pra pouca coisa.

Comment: Só quero que a <div> que possui a `class="tooltip.right"` apareça quando a pessoa clicar em um `<input>` com `class="form-control"`.

Comment: Do jeito que você fez, o `<input>` some quando é clicado. e a `<div>` surge.

Comment: Sim, são vários. Todos com as mesmas classes.

Comment: Tanto as `<div>`'s como os `<input>`'s

Comment: @AlexandreLopes ae complica se tem várias DIVs, eu nem sei como é a estrutura HTML toda, recomendo ler este topico: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve e tentar melhorar a pergunta, entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Gui, é possível fazer sem inserir uma `class=""`? Apenas `style="display:block"`? :)

Comment: @AlexandreLopes o primeiro exemplo é exatamente isso, sem classe. Veja que usei `div.style.display = "block";` e `div.style.display = "none";`

Comment: Vou testar aqui! :D

Comment: @AlexandreLopes se não conseguir me manda a estrutura HTML do formulário, ae faço as modificações para funcionar no teu form.

Comment: Vou te mandar aqui!

Comment: Olha ai o fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sLLdqmqx/

Comment: Já vou dando como resposta certa. :D

Comment: @AlexandreLopes isso é só um div e um input, eu pedi o formulário, preciso sabe a estrutura DOM modificar o código. Fico aguardando.